# ng-repeat not updating the view properly

Tags: angularjs, view, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have this code in my html.

```
<script>
    _sessionStorage.datatables.role_list.selected[0].unit_changer_criteria = {"test":"test"}
</script>

<div>
   {{_sessionStorage.datatables.role_list.selected[0].unit_changer_criteria}}
   <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in _sessionStorage.datatables.role_list.selected[0].unit_changer_criteria">{{key + ': ' + value}}</span>
</div>
```

I change " _sessionStorage.datatables.role_list.selected[0].unit_changer_criteria = {"test2":"test2"}; "

the {{..}} part updates in the DOM but the ng-repeat keeps the "test: test" in the DOM (it is not removed), and add "test2: test2" to the DOM. so it looks like:

test: test
test2: test2

when it should just say

test2: test2

Bare in mind the the {{..}} part of the DOM display the correct value, so the digest is triggered and the object is updated, and the value is added to the repeat in the DOM ... but it should update the repeat part of the DOM not just add it.

i have also tried to add "track by $index" and "track by key" with no luck.

does anybody have any idea whar could be the problem??

cheers
c_bb

Comment: Can you show us the code of your controller?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/UpcKp46gPzrAIl0mM9I9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with `ng-repeat`. If you update the list items, it won't reflect in. If you add `$scope.$apply()`, it will reflect.

Answer (score 0):

sorry ... i finally found my issue, it was in one of my directives ... sorry for wasting everybodys time. had been looking for the problem/answer for several hours, which lead me to answer this question.

everybody who answered .. a big thank you! Especially @Rejs ... that was the trigger to lead me in the right direction.

cheers
c_bb